# R: Pass model name as Parameter in Functions?

Tags: r

In R

```
 model_name(formula, data, ..)
```

i.e **model_name** can be one among *glm, rpart, randomForest ..etc.*

Lets say I have a function

```
callMyModel = function(model_name, formula, data)
{
    fit = model_name(formula, data)
}
```

I need an implementation as:

```
fit = callMyModel(glm, Y ~ ., mydata) #It should fit glm on my data
fit = callMyModel(rpart, Y ~ ., mydata) #It should fit rpart on my data
```

Can this be possible ? If so how ?

Note: I don't need an implementation with ***if*** conditions.

Comment: Have you run your own code? Your current implementation should work well...a better one could be `callMyModel = function(model_name, formula, data, ...){
    model_name(formula, data, ...)
}`

Comment: Thanks @PingJin. That works fine.